# 12.10 system with optimus, bumblebee and nvidia current wont install

Tags: nvidia, 12.10, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have a system with the optimus technology, when I try to install bumblebee-nvidia, I receive a message saying that I am missing nvidia-current (>= 260.19.12~) so, I go on and try to install nvidia-current. Now it is the xorg-video-abi-11 that is missing and that it cannot be installed.

Ok so I do a little search only to find out that xorg-video-abi-11 is part of xserver-xorg-core, obviously, it is already installed but I try to reinstall it and no luck, it only say it is already to the newest version....

Anyone have ideas ?

Comment: Shouldn't the optimus tag really be "fu nvidia"? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix it, turned out that for some reason, apt could not resolve dependencies. Nvidia-current depends on xorg-video-abi-11 OR xorg-video-abi-12 OR xorg-video-abi-13 but, is only looking at 11 and does not see it.

I manually downloaded nvidia-current and installed it:

```
apt-get install dkms

dpkg -i /home/mobidoy/Downloads/nvidia_current_304.51.really.304.43-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

apt-get install nvidia-settings

apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

reboot and voila !!!

Answer (score 0):

What card are you using?
You may need the repository `ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

(https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation)

Comment: It is a gtx620m, I already have the x-swat ppa but for precise as there is none yet for quantal.